# Issue with Concatenating Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

Hey I am trying to concatenate strings with javascript but I am having errors. Here is my code:

```
function popForm(){
   var v = document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML;

   document.getElementById("a1_i").innerHTML =
      "<input type='text' name='a1_i' value="+v+" />";
}
```

The element a1_i is a span that I am populating with the input tag shown above.

Further down I edit the element with ID a1:

```
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML="blah bloop";
```

However when I try to view the result, all I can see is blah, not bloop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be using DOM methods such as `createElement` and `appendChild` to build HTML, not string concatenation.

Comment: That's the general consensus I have gotten from looking up stuff online. This is just for a little project between me and my friends though so I didn't want to put time into it to learn something else. I figured out that I just missed some quotes though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the generated HTML, you can notice following:

```
<input type='text' name='a1_i' value=blah bloop />
```

As syntax highlighter suggests, value of the `value` attribute is `blah`, while bloop is another attribute. You just need to add quotes:

```
function popForm(){
  var v = document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML; 
  document.getElementById("a1_i").innerHTML="<input type='text' name='a1_i' value='" + v   + "' />";
}
```

But if `v` contains symbol `'`, then you're in trouble again. So you either should replace them with [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) or follow jbabey's advice.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Jbabey, it will save you extra coding of text/html strings (error prone) in the future.  JavaScript concatenation is pretty straight forward

```
*variable1 + "Text, note quotes around" + variablearray[1] + "etc...";*
```

Use the methods: document.createElement  document.createTextNode   appendChild

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild